# How to get downtime on Icinga?

Tags: icinga, icinga2, icingaweb2, icingaweb

I'm working on a project and we are using Icinga to monitor some services. However, we need to get a downtime from some services, but I can't find it.

For an example:

My service is UP, running for 5 mins.
Suddenly, service is down.
After 10 minutes, service is up again.

Okay, how can I get the 10 minutes of down service? I mean,I know that I can get two times (last time it was up, and when it came back up), but can I get this information somewhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the service history, either on the GUI (*icingaweb2* or another one), or with a request against:

- The [core API](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/12-icinga2-api/) ;
- Livestatus.